# How do you start each SpringBatch step with different parameters?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to springbatch and I am trying something where from a CSV file I am trying to read about 2000 records every 10 seconds using a quartz scheduler and write it into a database.
The problem is everytime it starts reading the file from the beginning and hence writes the same set of records into the database.
I've tried dynamically changing the paramter "setLinesToSkip" but to no avail, which is probably because it is included in my default bean definition.
Is there some way by which I can resume processing from the same spot or maybe can update the value in setlinetoskip

```
    @Bean
    public Step stepOne() {
    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("stepOne")
            .<Stock,Stock>chunk(5)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();

}

@Bean
public Job readCSVFileJob1() {
    return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("readCSVFileJob1")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(stepOne())
            .build();
}
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<Stock, Stock> processor(){
    return new DBLogProcessor();
}

 @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Stock> reader() {
     FlatFileItemReader<Stock> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<Stock>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        itemReader.setMaxItemCount(2000);
        itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("example.csv"));
        return itemReader;
    }
```